# Exact range of XP gain?

Tags: league-of-legends

- What is the exact range for me to be able to gain XP from a minion death without being near a minion wave?
- Is it different for each champion or each type of minion?
- Is it possible to see the range in-game?
- Does the range change as my size changes as well (like Zac and Cho'Gath)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your questions:

- The exact range is 1600 ([source](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Experience_(champion)#Experience_needed_to_level_up)) :

> Minion waves calculations assumes a Summoner's Rift lane, no increased experience sources, no neutral monsters are slain and one champion is in **1600 range of every opposing minion death in said lane**.

- The range remains the same but different units have different hitboxes.
- No there is no way to see an indicator for 1600 range (there is no champion with an ability with exactly that range. Just picture 16 teemos next to eachother (or a bit less than a rumble ult)
- The experience radius of the minion doesn't change but since your hitbox is larger you can stand a bit further out. (only the outer limit of your hitbox is needed for the experience). This is because the experience [range](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Range) is around the minion, not the champion and counts as a self targeted aura.

Comment: "The range doesn't change but since your hitbox does increase it's "easier" to be within range." - do you have any source for that? That sounds counter-intuitive.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I hope it clarifies it. I kinda don't know how the correct/elegant words in english...

Comment: I understood what you meant, I just don't believe that's how it works. Do you have a source saying your collision box needs to be within experience range, rather than the exact center of it?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer [The lolwiki article for range](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Range) says that auras are calculated from edge to edge. I wouldn't see why it's different here. Also (idk if that counts as source but) about 5000 hours of playing league and analyzing things like this.

Comment: Then why not go ahead and mention that?

Comment: I like to picture it being about trundle's passive range when you're hovering it. The exp range is a bit bigger so it helps leave room for user error too haha